# Blender renders plane in distorted way when enabling displacement only vs. bump displacement

Tags: displacement, height-map

I'm trying to use a plane with an image texture to render a topographic map of the US. When I add a subdivision modifier and use a *Bump Only* surface displacement, I have a fine looking map:

[image]

When I try to use *Displacement Only*, however, I get this much less fun looking thing:

[image]

Is there a reason for this, and if so, what can I do to avoid it?

Here's my set of settings for reference:

[image]

Comment: You may use a displacement node I think (hard to know as you don't show the node setting). See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/144897/problem-using-voronoi-texture-as-cycles-displacement-2-8/144917#144917

Comment: See also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/212930/how-do-you-remove-the-line-in-the-noise-texture/213041#213041

Answer (score 1):

You have the Strength property on the Displace modifier turned up too high. Turn it down to 0.1 (or lower).

Comment: I'm not seeing a strength property under the `Displacement` modifier. I've edited the main post to include the settings I'm seeing. Can you let me know where I should be looking?

Comment: @scrollex Add a "Math" node in between Color and Displacement, and adjust the value until it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're connecting your height map directly to the Displacement output. That doesn't typically work well - a better option is to include a "Displacement" node in between (found under Vector > Displacement, I think) with the height map as the "Height" input. That way you can adjust the "Scale" property on the node, which is the equivalent of the "Strength" property chirpywiz711 suggested (if you were using a modifier).