# Where Is Micro Displacement Setting Both/True/Bump In Blender 2.8

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, displacement

I'm currently following a Blender Guru tutorial for creating ropes. And in the tutorial, after adding a displacement texture, he continues to change the displacement setting under the material tab from "bump" to "true". However it seems that in Blender 2.8 this setting has been removed/relocated and I cant find it.

Researching on other websites hasn't given me the results I've been asking for. Does anybody know where this setting has been moved to?
Here is a picture of my material tab from Blender 2.8:

[image]

Here is also how I expect it to look after I have done everything correctly:

[image]

And here is how it Looks now:

[image]

Comment: maybe switch from Eevee to Cycles?

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE! Displacement works for Cycles render engine. Additionally should add a "displacement" node between the texture and the output.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my render engine issue. I changed it to Cycles now. However the main Problem still remains as adding a displacement node didnt physically change the tube as it should have given the tutorial I am watching. It still is the same low poly 8-sided tube it used to be which I want to change

Comment: Need to add subdivision (modifier, with simple option, not catmul) to make it work. You also have an experimental feature (see in Cycles panel) so that the subdiv can be dynamical.

Comment: Ah thank you. With this I found the Setting. Buuuuuuuuuut, it still doesnt geometrically change the mesh… I get the Feeling that I missed something fundamental, but even after thoroughly rewatching the tutorial multiple times and applying all of the Feedback I got from here, I still cant achieve the desired result. With your reccomendations, it improved the texturing so that now the Illusion of depth actually works fine, but the mesh remains to be a smooth, yet simple tube instead of the actual rope. I will add a picture of how I expect it to be in the original post for you to see.

Comment: @PauloWeissheimer, added the blend file as example for this question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/144897/problem-using-voronoi-texture-as-cycles-displacement-2-8/144917#144917 tell if doesn't help enough

Comment: Using your provided example and applying the changes, it actually did Change the shape of the mesh. Though not really in a way I would have predicted. I cant really describe what it changed, so I will post another picture of my rope in the post for you to see.

Comment: @PauloWeissheimer, should be "displacement" not "vector displcament" as I imagine you are using a height map. If still not good you should upload your file with textures included.

Comment: Okay so after changing that it again changed the geometry of the rope, but not in the desired way. The rope now has really sharp edges and the individual Strands dont really pop out. If you would maybe just shortly tell me how I can send you the Blender file, then I would gladly do so.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and found a solution that may help you.

1. Navigate to the *Material Properties* tab.
2. Within the *Material Properties* scroll down to a sub-setting titled *Settings*.
3. In settings change the displacement type from *Bump* to *Displacement and Bump*.

This seems to be the Blender 2.8 equivalent of the "True" setting.

Comment: Where is Displacement and bump in 2.83.2?

Answer (score 2):

Your 3rd step is the problem:
there is no displacement setting at all (see screenshot) !!!

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Go to *Scene* Tab, change render engine to *Cycles* then *Displacement* in setting property appears.

Answer (score 0):

Change render engine to cycles here on the second tab from the top.
[image]